# fortify is giving code correctness double check locking issue for the code

Tags: java, multithreading, security, volatile, fortify

```
Class MnetLdapHelper {

    private static volatile MnetLDAPService ldapSvc = null;
    public MnetLdapHelper() throws Throwable {
        if (ldapSvc == null) {
            synchronized(MnetLdapHelper.class) {
                if (ldapSvc == null) {
                    setup();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void setup() throws Throwable {
        PropertyManager appProp = PropertyUtil.getInstance()
            .getPropertyManager();
        try {

            sLog.info("MnetLdapHelper setup(+) ");
            ldapHost = appProp.getStringProperty("LDAP", "Host");
            ldapSslPOrt = Integer.valueOf(appProp.getStringProperty("LDAP", "Port"));
            ldapPort = Integer.valueOf(appProp.getStringProperty("LDAP", "NonSSLPort"));
            baseDn = appProp.getStringProperty("LDAP", "BaseDN");
            appCUID = appProp.getStringProperty("LDAP", "AppCUID");
            appPasswd = appProp.getStringProperty("LDAP", "AppPassword");
            groupBaseDn = appProp.getStringProperty("LDAPGROUPS", "GroupBaseDN");

            String appDN = null;
            int minConnInt = 1;
            int maxConnInt = 10;
            if (minConn != null && minConn.length() > 0) {
                minConnInt = Integer.parseInt(minConn);
            }
            if (maxConn != null && maxConn.length() > 0) {
                maxConnInt = Integer.parseInt(maxConn);
            }

            ldapSvc = new MnetLDAPService(ldapHost, ldapPort, false, null,
                null, baseDn, minConnInt, maxConnInt);

            LDAPEntry appEntry = ldapSvc.getUser(appCUID, null, null);
            if (appEntry == null) {
                sLog.error("Non-existent application CUID: [" + appCUID +
                    "], throw new Exception...");
                throw new Exception("Non-existent application CUID: [" +
                    appCUID + "]");
            }
            appDN = appEntry.getDN();
            sLog.info("appDN is: " + InfoSecValidation.cleanLogMessage(appDN));

            // Empty the non-SSL connection pool
            ldapSvc.finalize();

            ldapSvc = new MnetLDAPService(ldapHost, ldapSslPOrt, true, appDN,
                appPasswd, baseDn);
            // ldapSvc.setDisconnect(Boolean.parseBoolean(ldapApiDisconnectConnectionFlag));
            ldapSvc.setDisconnect(false);
            // ldapSvc.setUserSearchAttributes(IDATTRS);

        } catch (LDAPException ldEx) {
            if (ldapSvc != null) {
                ldapSvc.finalize();
                ldapSvc = null;
            }
            sLog.error(
                "LDAPException caught in setup(), throw new DocsServiceException... " +
                ldEx.errorCodeToString(), ldEx);
            throw ldEx;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            if (ldapSvc != null) {
                ldapSvc.finalize();
                ldapSvc = null;
            }
            sLog.error(
                "Throwable caught in setup(), throw new DocsServiceException",
                ex);
            throw ex;    
        }
    }    
}
```

This above code is being used in my application . Previously I was getting code correctness : Double check locking fortify issue when I was not using volatile , then I found that we can solve this problem by using volatile keyword but issue is still there can someone help me what is wrong here

Comment: If you are using Java in version 5 or later, the code should work as intended. See [this reference](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html).

Comment: oh sorry @Turing85 i just mistyped this , no i want to synchronization on MnetLdapHelper only?

Comment: It might be complaining because `ldapSvc` isn't assigned in this code.

Comment: we are assigning ladpSvc in setup method

Comment: @Turing85 we are using java 1.7

Comment: @jitendravarshney sure; but does your tool know that? Can you make `setup()` return the value, e.g. `ldapSvc = setup();`?

Comment: @AndyTurner i dont know how HP fortify works ? it is 3rd part tool only to observing security gap in application

Comment: @jitendravarshney I don't either. I'm simply saying it *might* expect double-checked locking to actually assign the thing you're checking.

Comment: @AndyTurner ok i  have added setup method

Comment: "`public void setup()`" well, that's worrysome: anybody can call this to reassign the `ldapSvc`, right? And would that have to be static?

Comment: @AndyTurner code is perfect but Fortify is giving issue

Comment: Nah!  Code is not perfect.

Comment: @jitendravarshney we're not HP customer support. If you think their tool is broken, talk to them. All we can do is to suggest reasons why we, as human reviewers, might consider this code to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your solution.  The problem is that the `setup()` method can be called at any time by any thread, and that it changes the state of the private static by a side-effect.

A better solution is to change `setup()` to create and return a `MnetLdapHelper` instance, and the assign the result of to the `static`.

```
class MnetLdapHelper {

    private static  volatile MnetLDAPService ldapSvc = null;

    public MnetLdapHelper() {
        if (ldapSvc == null) {
            synchronized (MnetLdapHelper.class) {
                if (ldapSvc == null) {
                    ldapSvc = setup();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private MnetLDAPService setup() {
        MnetLDAPService res = ...
        // initialize it
        return res;
    }
}
```

Now it is debatable whether Fortify's is correct in reporting your version as an incorrectly implemented double-checked lock.  It could be that the heuristic that Fortify is using is incorrect.

But that is moot if you can rewrite the code to satisfy Fortify.  I think you will find that my version will do that.

---

I would also take issue with any method or constructor that is declared as `throws Throwable`.  You should change this to list *only* the checked exceptions that you *expect* to be thrown.

Finally the way that you are using a `static` here is likely you cause problems for unit testing `MnetLdapHelper` or other code that uses a `MnetLdapHelper` instance.

Comment: means  you are saying that if i implemented my code as yu suggested fortify will not detect this as an issue ?

Comment: That's what I wrote.  Try it and see.

Comment: i will try it and lets see fortify detect or not thanx for your suggestion